# User updating of has_many :through associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, has-and-belongs-to-many

In my app, the administrator of a company defines a set of attributes to be associated with a location (for example, market size and geographical location).  They also define which values are acceptable for a given attribute (only one for each attribute for each location).  Since there is not a fixed number of attributes, I am using HMT for this association.  In effect, location.attributes contains the attributes associated with the location.  I want, in the location view, to allow the user to select the values for each attribute.  I want those values to then update the HMT association.  I can only find the brute force approach of creating a hash with those attributes, populating select tags with the choices, and then processing the hash coming back to Update manually, assigning the selections made by the user to the HABTM collection (location.attributes = params[location][attributes]).  This seems like something that is common enough that ROR should have a more built-in way to do this.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: umm not sure if this might help, but try and check out ryan bates 'railscasts', maybe episodes http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 and http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-2 might give you a hint

Comment: Still not quite getting everything with respect to the setting of attributes and acceptable values. For a given location, a) does admin choose to include market size, but maybe not geographical location; and b) then for market size chooses what the market size is, or chooses several values that can be chosen for market size?

Comment: I resolved this issue the right way (I think) using _accepts_nested_attributes_ and _fields_for_ on the actual association values instead of creating a hash of values from the association.  I was reinventing the wheel (my usual ROR sin)

Comment: that's the way to do it, for sure. Did the Railscasts linked above help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ingo had the correct answer, pointing me to the nested forms railcasts.  Thanks!